# Saving a Base64 string to disk as a binary using PHP

Tags: php, binary, base64

As a "look under the covers" tutorial for myself I am building a PHP script to gather emails from a POP3 mailbox.  While attempting to make use of binary attachments I am stuck trying to figure out what to do with the attachment information.

Given a string that would be gathered from an email:

> ------=_Part_16735_17392833.1229653992102
>   Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=trans2.jpg
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   X-Attachment-Id: f_fow87t5j0
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=trans2.jpg
>
> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4QxrRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUA
>   AAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAUAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAhodp
>
> (...)
>
> EAgEAgEAgEAgEAg8IBQRL/Lbe/tJrScHqZ2lkmE4XUP2XcSDZZ2VvZ28dtbsDIYmhkbRxAIJCAQC
>   AQCAQf/ScyAQCAQCAQCAQCAQCAQCAQCAQCAQCAQf/9k=
>   ------=_Part_16735_17392833.1229653992102--

Is there a way to save off the data to disk so that it would be in a usable format?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pass the data to [base64_decode()](http://php.net/base64_decode) to get the binary data, write it out to a file with [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

Answer (score 9):

If you have a lot of data to write out that needs to be decoded before writing I would suggest using stream filters so decode the data as you write it...

```
$fh = fopen('where_you_are_writing', 'wb');
stream_filter_append($fh, 'convert.base64-decode');

// Do a lot of writing here. It will be automatically decoded from base64.

fclose($h);
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the below but did not work for me, was generating an empty image file.

```
file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($base64string));
```

this is how it worked for me:

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4';

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);
```

I took the code from : 
[How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

Comment: just the `list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);` fixed my code. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function base64_decode_file($data)
{
    if(preg_match('/^data\:([a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+);base64\,([a-zA-Z0-9\+\/]+\=*)$/', $data, $matches)) {
        return [
                'mime' => $matches[1],
                'data' => base64_decode($matches[2]),
        ];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I guess this was down voted because it doesn't specifically answer the question but its a very useful little helper so I'm tossing you an upvote.

Comment: BTW, you had a few redundant escape characters in your regex: `if(preg_match('/^data:([a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+);base64,([a-zA-Z0-9+\/]+=*)$/', $data, $matches)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Chop off first and last line, **base64decode** and save under given filename.

done.

Answer (score 0):

While reinventing the wheel has some entertainment and educational value, I would try to resist the temptation: [Mailparse](http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse), [Mail_mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, and this is what I did. As noted earlier, make sure to remove the extraneous lines before and after the base64 string.

```
<?php
$INPUT = "inputfile_base64_encoded.txt";
$OUTPUT = "output_decoded.zip";
$contents = file_get_contents($INPUT);
$bin = base64_decode($contents);
file_put_contents($OUTPUT, $bin);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

For big base64 strings from a DB you need use load()

```
$imgdata = $FromDB['BASE64']->load();
$imgdata =  base64_decode($imgdata);
file_put_contents($fileName, $imgdata);
```

Comment: What type of object is $FromDB['BASE64']? plain string data is not an object in php

Comment: @Mohammed Farag A varchar field from the database is an object, using the load method you can load a big amount of characters.