# Saving a Base64 string to disk as a binary using Delphi 2007

Tags: web-services, delphi, base64, delphi-2007

I have a Base64 binary string that is part of an XML document that is sent to us by a 3rd party supplier, I would like to be able to save it back to its original file format (jpg).

Using the accepted answer from this question ["saving a base64 string to disk as a binary using php"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380922/saving-a-base64-string-to-disk-as-a-binary-using-php) I can save the string to a jpg with little effort, so I know the string is in good form and is a JPG file.

But how do I do this in Delphi 2007?

Looking on the net I found a tutorial on how to convert the Base64 into a TByteDynArray, and save that, but it doesn't work right.  I have also played about with Indy's IdDecoderMIME, but with with no success.

Does any one know how to do this, or where I should be looking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OmniXMLUtils.pas from the [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) project contains following functions:

```
function  Base64Decode(encoded, decoded: TStream): boolean; overload;
function  Base64Decode(const encoded: string; decoded: TStream): boolean; overload;
function  Base64Decode(const encoded: string; var decoded: string): boolean; overload;
function  Base64Decode(const encoded: string): string; overload;
procedure Base64Encode(decoded, encoded: TStream); overload;
procedure Base64Encode(decoded: TStream; var encoded: string); overload;
function  Base64Encode(decoded: TStream): string; overload;
function  Base64Encode(const decoded: string): string; overload;
procedure Base64Encode(const decoded: string; var encoded: string); overload;
```

The Base64Decode(string, TStream) should do the trick. For the TStream parameter you can pass it TFileStream like this:

```
procedure SaveBase64ToFile(const encoded, fileName: string);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    if not Base64Decode(encoded, fs) then
      raise Exception.Create('Invalid data!');
  finally FreeAndNil(fs); end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Direct (Indy) library contains classes in IdCoderMIME.pas which support Base64 encoding and are easy to use: TIdEncoderMIME and TIdDecoderMIME.