# Base64 encoded String to binary file

Tags: arrays, delphi, base64, binaryfiles

I have a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded String that contains PDF data. Using the `EncdDecd` unit I can decode the String to a Byte Array.

This is where I am having trouble: I tried saving the characters to a String but once it hits a zero value (ASCII = `0` or `#0` or `$00`) the String no longer appends. Example:

```pascal
uses
  EncdDecd;
var
  EncodedString : String;
  Report : String;
  Base64Bytes: TBytes; // contains the binary data
begin
  Base64Bytes := DecodeBase64(EncodedString);
  for I := 0 to Length(Base64Bytes) - 1 do
    begin
      Report := Report + Chr(Base64Bytes[I]);
    end;
```

Writing to a text file seems to work better but after renaming it to `.PDF` the file does not open correctly.

How can I write to a binary file in Delphi? Or even save the data to a stream? Basically I am just trying to **take the encoded String and save it to a PDF/binary file, or display the PDF in Delphi**.

I have looked around quite a bit and found a possible solution in
[Saving a Base64 string to disk as a binary using Delphi 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690475/) but is there another way?

Comment: Duplicate of [Saving a Base64 string to disk as a binary using Delphi 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690475/saving-a-base64-string-to-disk-as-a-binary-using-delphi-2007). I don't see what *new* information you're requesting here. If you just want additional options, they belong as answers to the original question, not this duplicate.

Comment: what have you tried? what was the problem? How do you "append" the string? please post your code using "EncdDecd namespace". Also, how do you change a text file to a pdf? again post your code. There are many ways in Delphi to transform a string and save it in binary. The link you posted is quite a compact code to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
procedure DecodeBaseToFile(const FileName: string; 
  const EncodedString: AnsiString);
var
  bytes: TBytes;
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  bytes := DecodeBase64(EncodedString);
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  try
    if bytes<>nil then
      Stream.WriteBuffer(bytes[0], Length(bytes));
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Note**: I have only compiled this in my head.

Comment: @Trevor: you can alternatively use a `TByteStream` instead.  It is a `TMemoryStream` descendant, so it has a `SaveToFile()` method available.  That way, you don't have to instantiate `TFileStream` manually.

Comment: @Trevor: upvoted it for you, but you'll have to accept it as the answer yourself (check mark underneath the up/down vote arrows).

Comment: I created a empty unit, in uses need uses System.Classes, System.SysUtils, synacode, IdCoder, IdCoderMIME;  and I need change the line Decodebase64 to  bytes := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeBytes(EncodedString);

Comment: @MárcioRossato That's using a different base64 encoder

Comment: yes, I need change because I have not found the correct uses.