# save base64 image from javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a variable in JavaScript name as `myImage` which holds the `base64` encoded string of an image like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE......` Now I want to save this image on folder at server side. Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string

Answer (score 4):

You need to work on asking questions a little better, but I will try to give you a basic explanation.

Step one: Pass the base64 string to the server.

Step two: Strip the first parts and last parts.

Step three: base64_decode the string.

Step four: file_put_contents the result of that.

Of course this is very basic, but there are already answers out there for this, and I was able to find even more with a google search.

Answer (score 2):

The below code does the trick:

Here you are just writing the data to a file and saving it in the write format

```
var data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile('image.png', buf,function(err, result) {
      if(err){console.log('error', err);}
    });
```

The resulting image will be stored as image.png  at the current directory