# Jquery to print after submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to use jquery to print and here i have a button to perform this taxk but I want this to be printed after the form submission.

here is my code that prints the content on button click event, after printing ti will submit the form.. how can i do this..

```html
<button  id="btnjson" type="submit" value="ok" class="button" onclick="printDiv('print-table')">Ok</button>



<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
 //alert('s');
 var printContents = '<div id="print-content"><form><table width="100%"  height="100" ><tbody >';
  var inputs, index;
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input,select');
printContents+='<div style="width:765px; float:left; height:72px;">'
printContents +='</tbody></table>';
 w=window.open();
 w.document.write(printContents);
 w.print();
 w.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Print where? on  console  ? or on UI? do you want to stop the screen before submission?

Comment: yes i want to stop screen before submission

Comment: if submit is done then it will be print if have any problem in submit like validations and all than it will not print

Comment: hey @Gulshan how could it works

Comment: i cant do this bcoz this button related to my form submission

Comment: i can also do other stuff by this

Comment: not working same

Comment: nothing change..

Comment: no i can do it right

Comment: its not working

Comment: remove unwanted comments @manika and put a green tick if you feel the question is answered correctly by someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I did for printing invoices after successful response from backend is follows:

```
var mywindow = window.open('_blank', '', '');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body onload="setTimeout(myFunction(){window.print();}, 3000)">');  
var printContents = '<style>@media print {  .print_hide{display: none;} } </style>';
printContents += '<div id="print-content"><form><table width="100%" height="100"><tbody>';
var inputs, index; inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input,select'); 
printContents+='<div style="width:765px; float:left; height:72px;">';
printContents +='</tbody></table>';
mywindow.document.write(printContents);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');                        
mywindow.document.close();
```

It will open a new window...

Comment: hey i also dont want everything in print in this i use selected inputs for printing

Comment: For specific content printing use CSS with ".print_hide" class and apply to ignored ones.....also add  @media print { .print_hide{display: none;} } in CSS

Comment: i cant understand what u want to say

Comment: var printContents = '<div id="print-content"><form><table width="100%"  height="100" ><tbody >';
  var inputs, index;
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input,select');
printContents+='<div style="width:765px; float:left; height:72px;">';
printContents +='</tbody></table>';

Comment: because i write css also hear for every values postion on page

Comment: var printContents = '<style>@media print { .print_hide{display: none;} } </style>';
printContents += '<div id="print-content"><form><table width="100%" height="100"><tbody>';

Comment: apply print hide class to ignored elements.

Comment: hey its move me on a page

Comment: that is looking weird and also through on blank

Comment: on current tab its not happning??

Comment: i want a page in same window

Comment: Try editing ur self ...it will improve ur skills ....Here most of the people will guide u d way ...rest u have to code ur self....sorry.

Comment: my previous is better but a little bit problem that i wanted to fix out

Answer (score 1):

You can do in 2 ways.

1- can generate a screenshot using [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792805/how-to-take-screenshot-of-canvas)

2- you may use jquery to hide elements and get print done before form submission

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be printed after job submission, you may have to send the data to be back-end and store it and then retrieve it. Using Session scope variables etc.