# Where the screenshot is being made in the html2canvas()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm trying to upload screenshot to server through php or ajax. But I can't figure out Where the screenshot is being made in the html2canvas()? I have searched about that but didn't find solution. Please review my code and guide me.

### JS Code

```
$(function () {
  $("#btnSave").click(function () {
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        $('#captured_img').attr("src", image);
        $('#img_val').attr("value", image);
      }
    });
  });
```

### HTML Code

```
<div id="widget" class="widget">
  <h1>THE IMAGE</h1>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value=""/>
<div id="showImage">
  <img id="captured_img" src="" height="120" width="100"/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>
```

Comment: Are you able to view it in `captured_img` after `onrendered` ? DO you want to view the image or save it iver server ? Also note `image/jpeg` does not support a transparent background, use `png`

Comment: @RayonDabre yes I can view in `captured_img` after `onrendered`. I want to upload image on php server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `image/jpeg` does not support a transparent background, use `image/png`
>
> `html2canvas` will return you `canvas` of your `DOM`, you can get `base64` data using `toDataURL` method of canvas. To upload `base64` as image, you need to decode the base64 data. `file_put_contents` Write a string to a file.
>
> Use following script:

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {
    $img = $_REQUEST['data'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = rand(0000000, 1131231) . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    if ($success!==false) {
        echo 'done';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

**HTML & JS:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('widget'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $('#captured_img').attr("src", image);
        $('#img_val').attr("value", image);
        $.post("decode.php", {
            data: image
          })
          .done(function(data) {
            alert("Status: " + data);
          });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="widget" class="widget">
  <h1>THE IMAGE</h1>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />

<div id="showImage">
  <img id="captured_img" src="" height="120" width="100" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG" />
```

Comment: Thanks its working but what are next step how can i upload file on server. I want to upload image once form submit. Now i'm getting DONE status in `alert`

Comment: In above script, image is being uploaded using `ajax`. If you want to upload on form submit, you can use the `php` script provided but read the data from `img_val`(hidden field)

Comment: you mean I have to store `$success` in `img_val`(hidden field) ?

Comment: **NO** If you are submitting the form then there is no need to use `ajax`. Submit the form using `$('form_id').submit()` once you set the value of the hidden field.

Comment: Alright thanks can you please let me know why `$success` return me this `6873` when i `print` it so how can i upload this is still not image?

Comment: Just check your root directory to find the image. This number is `number of bytes that were written to the file`

Comment: Alright files generating successfully but does not showing properly. Image viewer giving me this error (`Windows photo viewer can't display this picture because the file is empty.`) When i open

Comment: Using `ajax` or `form-submit` ?

Comment: `form-submit` using this

Comment: use `setTimeout()` of 10ms after setting hidden field value as its huge data. Also check what value you are getting using `var_dump($_REQUEST['img_val'])`

Comment: I'm getting this `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk....."` in result of `var_dump($_REQUEST['img_val'])`

Answer (score 1):

Your image is not creating in any file system it's just a base64 encoded string `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");` assigned to the image source. 
You can send that string to ajax call and make a file in php function. for more details on how to create image from base64 string here is the link [dataurl to image for download in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230573/dataurl-to-image-for-download-in-php).