# fwrite() - image may be damaged after writing as png

Tags: php, fwrite

I am trying to download an image to the server then send to client-side for local download, the image data will come from google charts. (Google chart currently doesn't support 'download chart as image').

It is now downloading to the server but I cannot open it, it says:

```
"It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."`
```

(*I'm using Mac*).

Should I decode it? I don't know, need your help.

Here is my code:

JavaScript

```
$.post('ajaxrequest.php', {
    func: 'saveImageToServer',
    case: imgData,
    param: 'sample001001'
    }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

PHP:

```
if($request == 'saveImageToServer') {
    //Get the file
    $image = $case;

    // write it
    $filename = $param;
    $file = "./downloadedcharts/".$filename.".png";

    $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    if(fwrite($fh, $image)) {
        fclose($fh);
        echo "download success";
    } else {
        echo "error";   
    }

}
```

Here is a sample of image data that I am passing:

```
data:image/png;base64,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`
```

Comment: @Ignacio what do you mean?

Comment: Run `file` against the file. What does it say?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying or referring to.

Comment: the usual way to save an uploaded file is to grab the temp name of the uploaded file from `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` and use the php function `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Open a terminal. Find the file you downloaded. Put its path as the first argument of the command "file".

Comment: @danyamachine the file is not being uploaded thru a form, the file is being written to the server using the data generated from the chart after clicking the button "Download"

Comment: @Ignacio it says "ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators", what does this mean?

Comment: heyyyy @clintgh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string nice explanation of how to write base64 strings to an image. The gotcha here is that you are skipping the step of converting to binary first.

Comment: Fixed, thanks to @chiliNUT

Answer (score 1):

Just like Jack said, on my server, PHP created corrupt files, i only added the line

```
stream_filter_append($imagen, 'convert.base64-decode');
```

before the fwrite() function 
and all works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write base64 encoded data into a file and expect it to work; it needs to be decoded first:

```
$f = fopen('output.png', 'wb');
stream_filter_append($f, 'convert.base64-decode');
fwrite($f, substr($case, strpos($case, ',') + 1));
fclose($f);
```