# AngularJS : Upload base64 image to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, file-upload, base64

I've generated a base64 data of an image and fed it into the src attribute of the `<img/>` tag so now the image appears. But now next task is to upload the image file from the `<img/>` tag to the server. But since I've the base 64 of the image I don't know how to upload it to the server.

Please guide.

Comment: Couldn't you POST/GET the base64 to the server then convert it there? [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11511605/4777622)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned send it across as a base64 and convert it on the server. It's already been coded to a base64, there is no need to convert it to an image, ie bmp, jpeg, etc., and take the performance hit of encoding the immediately decoding to send.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the Base 64 data to the server throw a normal AJAX POST.

Even with jQuery: 
`$.post('/save', {image: base_64_data})`

Then in the server, as mentioned [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string) (PHP Example), you can save the image on disk or do whatever you want.