# How to save base64 string as image server-side

Tags: php, base64, decode

I want to save a base64 string as an image (.png or .jpg) on my server.

The string I get looks like this: 
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA[...]"

I tried this:

```
$data = $_POST['form_new_data'];
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        file_put_contents("/userImgs/pic.jpg",$data);
```

but it is not working (maybe because the base64 string is a jpeg?).. Please help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
$data = $_POST['form_new_data'];
file_put_contents('img.jpg', base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data)));
```

Comment: you forgot stripping the prefix ;-P

Comment: realized after posting it. It is fine now rt?

Comment: thank you, works, but can you tell me, why mine is not working? I used the code from the accepted answer of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string @georoot

Comment: @user3375021 to be frank i am not sure why explode is being used at all. I would say try to print $data in your script just before you store it to a file and compare it with the output of preg_replace in my script

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you!