# How to export image from cropit to php for upload?

Tags: php, jquery

I've been searching the internet for a while now and cannot find anything that tells me how I turn the result from `$('#image-cropper').cropit('export')` into an image that PHP can upload to the server. I'm using the Cropit plugin and all I need is an image that I can pass into my php upload script. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="image-cropper">
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" />
    <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />
    <button class="export">Export</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
            var username = "<?php echo $userData['username']; ?>";
            $('#image-cropper').cropit({
                imageState:{
                    src:'users/'+username+'/profile_picture.jpg'
                },
            });   

            $('#image-cropper').cropit('previewSize', {width:500, height:500});


            $('.export').click(function() {
                var imageData = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export');
                //$("#code").val(imageData);
                window.open(imageData);
            });
```

The code here is working properly for the plugin but I'm unable to turn the result which looks something like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD...` into an image that I can use in a php script. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You can find solution for your issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string hope this helps

Comment: @CihanUygun I"m able to put it into a file format now but the issue is that it's cutting the top part off the image. Basically it's only saving about a quarter way down from the top.

Comment: can you paste data:image/png;base64..... this data to your browser's address bar, are the images are same or different than file one ?

Comment: I was able to get the clipping fixed but the saved image was too small so I made the preview bigger which gives me a larger saved file but brought the clipping back. The clipping only occurs when I export it with the answer from that post you gave me when I just visit the url there is no clipping. I will post my current code above. Also is there a way to make the quality better

Comment: Is there a way I can bump up the quality of the image and save it in a bigger size without having to make the preview box larger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I got it to work is by messing around with the quality settings of Cropit and creating a PHP function that reads the base64 string and converts it to an image.

The code below is for cropit. I'm setting a timeout because if you don't it will send the form to php before cropit can create the base64. The base64 string is just stored in a text field which php can communicate based on `$_POST`

```
//Initiate Cropper
$('.image-editor').cropit();

//Assign Export Function
$('.export').click(function() {
    var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export', {
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        quality: 0.33,
        originalSize: true,
    });

    //Set value of hidden input to base64
    $("#hidden_base64").val(imageData);

    //Pause form submission until input is populated
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.upload_form.submit();
        alert(imageData);
    }, 1000);
});
```

The code below is for php. It works by decoding the base64 then moving it to a specified directory.

```
function decode ($code, $username) {
    list($type, $code) = explode(';', $code);
    list(, $code)      = explode(',', $code);
    $code = base64_decode($code);

    file_put_contents('directory/filename.jpg', $code);
}
```