# Dark image get while saving a png through PHP

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to save a captured image from  HTML5/Canvas with a mobile. I am using PHP (symfony2).
I followed the instructions from this post ([How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string#_=_)) but I get a dark  empty image saved instead of what I captured.

Here is my JavaScript post code:

```
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path("personne_photo_capture",{"id":entity.personne.id}) }}",
    data: {
        imgBase64: dataUrl
    }
}).done(function (msg) {
    $('#msg').html(msg); 

}).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#msg').html(xhr.responseText);
});
```

And the PHP saving code :

```
$rawData = $_POST['imgBase64'];
if (isset($rawData)) {
    $filteredData = explode('base64,', $rawData);
    $data = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);  
    $filename = "profil.png";
     file_put_contents('picts/small/' . $filename, $data);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

Comment: just curious, what happens if you do var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); var img=document.createElement("img");img.src=dataUrl; document.body.appendChild(img);

Comment: wow, i have the same problem, the base64 from CHROME 48 is useless (invalid png format), but the base64 from FIREFOX 43 works just fine! ... try your code in firefox, does it work then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure to specify the datatype on the cliente side as

```
 dataType: 'text',
```

On the server side replace your first two statements with :

```
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
```

For further pointers take a loop at previously asked question

[How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

Comment: the explode code looks good to me, i doubt that preg_replace will do anything better