# Blank image saving in yii2 response coming from ios

Tags: php, yii2

I have writing register api in Yii2 for ios.I am saving image in uploads folder and image name in database.All is working fine but image is empty when i open it.
My code is

```
$image_data = base64_decode($_POST['user_image']);
$file_name = Yii::getAlias('@imagepath') .'/uploads/user/' ;
$image_name = substr(uniqid(rand(1,6)), 0, 8).'.png';
$file = $file_name . $image_name;

$success = file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

if($success){

$seller = new User();
$seller->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$seller->user_image = $image_name;
if($seller->save()){
    echo json_encode([
                'status'=>true,
                'msg'=>'success',
                ],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
```

How can I save correct image?Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you inspected whether `image` is coming from correct path or not ?

Comment: yes..image saved properly in path.when i go to uploads folder and open that image ...its totally blank

Comment: Check that image extension in upload folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)