# Parsing drag and drop images from Google image search

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, google-image-search

I wrote code to receive and handle images dropped from a computer and any webpage where the dropped value is a URL of some kind, but I can't receive images from Google image search because they're some kind of inline base64 image that I'm sure there's some way of parsing and handling it. Here's what it looks like:

```
<img data-sz="f" name="BC5TrHpnDUchoM:" class="rg_i rg_ic" alt="Image result for ecchi girl" jsaction="load:str.tbn" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUTExIWFhUXGRcYGBgYGBgXFxoXFxUWGBoYGBUYHSggGholHRUXIjEiJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGy0lICUtLS0vLS8tLS0tLy0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS4tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIARUAtgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQADBgIBB//EAEAQAAIBAgQDBgQEBQMCBgMAAAECEQADBBIhMQVBUQYiYXGBkRMyobFCwdHwFFJicuEjgpKiwgdDY7LS8RYzNP/EABoBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEAQIFAAb/xAAtEQACAgEEAQQABQQDAAAAAAAAAQIRAwQSITFBEyJRYSMyM3HwBUKRoRTB4f/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A+4VKlSuOJUrg3K5N2poq5pFtSqlJNWAVBKdntSpUriSV5NSaxPa3tG5Js4dso2e4N/FU/wDl7dahySVsvCDm6Q64z2qw2HOVnzN/KuseZ5VnG7fMxOVFUerH30FZlMIq6xJJGp1JJ8TR9hI19KXlmHY4Mce+TQYPtcxPeI8sv/1Tyxx0HkD5R+tZC3HSq8QoHeRfMSR6g7g0J5X4Zd4sb8H0XC45LnynXod/ahuJ8atWHRbhy55ho006+9fN24w9sgyQRsTv6MND61f2j42MTYtXJ79t4PirDX1kD60zhm5OpAlpVvSfTN9Y41ae4qIwYMSARsSq5jHh401r5LwDiKWr9i5duBURbjknUktKgADUmt3gO1dm8YRXjqco+kzRH7fzMHn02yVR5H9SuUea6rk0xUlSpUqTiCpUFSuOOXaKrZ+VeXG1qs1ZIWnk+D0mvBXhq21bqz4BxTkyy2D+/wBa7qVKGOJUiVKleGuJEXa7ihs2YX530H2+sgetYbDkTcdhmCaDkDcbc+nLxPhRPbjima+IMhM0ea6f+6faldu5lFm353G8Tv8Acilsttmjhx7YIvtJmvBOVsGf7iAPoAaPuhRbtHmSZ/3NAof+GNkqrfO4Zm/uMaemgri/clLA8bf6/lQJLmgjRfYuCLnVXgeqj8z9KtskG5DfKcp06NIJHkRQd+2UUnrluH/kfplIruw8XlB/lI9JBH2PvUNHUVYxChIgkSRyjQ678qz+MBfMLSAROZge7p15EzWt4rYDAqdJPLwGaPUA0k4q4SzlUQXkDrlHzH8vWiYmd9Ca61xrKMbYgGeUqrCAInVSR6Vqey+LjKQ7AbbKB5abetZ3gl+7bebTQwiAdVOhBUg8jMVqMTjrbW1xdq2LVxbgt37Y+WSpIOX0rQ1tZHaOjCcIrd0z6JgcQGUa8qMBrE8F4prvoGX2cVpLeN7wjWZ913Ht9qy8eZwkovoSy4qYzqUKMasxDz0yN94j60VWgnYuQVKgqVJwJUqGoKKIHqj1PSiRVdpatobGsUaRKlSq795UBZjAFQFO5pBx7j4to3wyM2veOonw6n6VXxLiRcRqF6bE+f6VnOJjMjeR9NPpVd19DuHTeZmKxOIzBTP4ee+rEzWn4LgmuYgEAQABr0UBjoPSspxO1kLL0DD/AIlo+wrTZMU2FGIwzFV+FcYlVDOzhlUIJ26+lWeHckhrJJRRo+M8Ndyr6ShbadQRrv5CldrAl8ij8Jj65R/76F7Cccv3L/8AD37hdiHBDIVe26agE/iDCeWkVtcJw/4d2Y0bbwYT+/SgajTyxT2yArMtoq4xwosNDtpAA2iI9qy5RkNokyVYIdIMEgA+w+td/wDiBg8baZXW/dIK3HbJoiQdAAPA6mknA8XeuOoLtctTafNcUBpPe3XQiVbXwpiWhl6Xq+CYZVJpGm4hehh4NaPu5U/Q0jxFolmL6kA6dEUwo9WijeLvLN52h/1E01OD+NctW1VQWLFiFA7qt3c0b6k684pfCtpeTrk97P8AZM3FtXNlcPnPMFXOUjzED0rntng7Nl7dm3OZoe4SZlUkLI23Jr6JhrAtoqLsoAHpXy7tS2fHXDO6lF/2qQAPUfWjtOS4AY888kqb4QBwPFkMR4r/ANLgVuOBX85HUXT7RB+5rAYQZGa5yYSP757w85j0mtT2VukG0eWYSf72gUhkj70/sJm5i2fRKlSpT5mkFSoKlccLg0mBqaKtWuZoOxbb+YAdAf0olVie8ff7VebS4EMF9tBVSuFapcuhQSTAFUHk7PL90KpZjAFJr5a53m0H4V6Dqf6vtRDk3CCRAHyr+Z8ftUursoEk0GUr4QzjW3l9izPb0DASdvHyFV4vAK6kCyZMwQh56b7U/wAJglt8pY7n8h4URNWjjOlq6ftPhvH7DLcKsCGAOad5Bg+nP1rTf+GfEQ2Hu4Z9QCdN+7cEEe4PvTHt5w7O9y4B3ktW28INx1M+ke1YjsxxQYTFC4w/0nlLg/lBI73oQPSad278TrtDW5ZYWfSeC8EWxc+LnLx8oKIpGmWWZRLkLoC0mK0tm4GUMNjVNtlKZkh9JWCIbSRB8etKh2jgf/z3AehK79N6RnKUncmKrHudQR32hwq3lAJyspJV4krIg6HQgjcEEVk8bb+CBaVy5LKzsVVYCjuqAogDfStlhcX8a3nNs29SACQSQOen70rAdqeIqHZU/BInq5+Y+kD2qHlnW1PgY0+ON21yjnAcPfFXO6YUXASd9EjTz0re8M4aLTF1MswAJYA6DkIiBSjsyq2kCkiYEbAx1y8pMn8+j7+NUb0JMtnt8BD4ojS4hy/zKSR6gaj6isZ264WWb4trbKrAjadhHmAPUeNbFL4YaUISqfOBkGYNO2RzM+Qb6NTOHI7FEnB2j5PhsWJkrIb5021nUr05+VbLgDoIQNKuvcbnntkOAeh3/ZrI32S5iCUXKpdmA37oYkE9DET501FwKEYd2WDCOo5joYqmojtkmOSW6NH1sGvaX8JxZuICdxueR8fpR9Ei1JWjLdp0z2pXk1Kk6xbaw4Ajfr4mrgAJrha6ZwBJOg3oO5sThFJUj29eCiTt9/ADrQoJcgtoBsvTz8aqSbjZyIH4QeQ6n+o/TajQIFc2aOPHsXPZySFFEYW3AzEan6Cgrf8AqXI/CsFvM/Kv5nwA60ZisZbt/PcVfMwfarQj5OyN9ItY15S5uOYcCfigjqJP2oTEdqsMi5izEeCk/eKOlfQFYMsnxF/4CuL4RTbvlpJuJkHXQHKB45mJ9a+U8R7LYpG1tnNzjUHxBFbm92/sbrZuuOsIPYFqCx/a/wCOmVUe0DuWI739Gm0/lR8TnB8If0+HURdbeGZzsr2gv4XNbYFra/hJiD0UmNPCtphOOYbEL8UdYIIOaekDfesJi8KVujuE5vlC+P75+NPuz/D2tLckfM0qs7QOZGnPlQtTGLW7yPSwRXPkO43xp8jZRkUA/wB222miisFbwzumgJZtP+Ta+u9aXjFkurZmIgfJEa9ZHze8VT2bsmLTc/l/3rqB6xSL9qs5xWNcGjwOAtlLVxw3wriqJ3NtwI1Md5CRvWuXA2wI+Gsf2iq7OFU2BbX5YETuOf0o8CjxSMfLJyfbEz2BaeBopEjw6j6g1Vxq0zWLmT5sjAeMjUfSi+PXlt2wzGO8oHmxivLDTQ5e2SaC423G2fIOHRluNzggf9RP/bRuPua2o2CD/kVB+wo/tbw0YW9nAi1dct4AsIYe8H1oCyJTKSZRonoNMrDrGnoT0o+dqfvGovyfUuAwLKa7if8AFM6QdnOIo65NVZfwnkDr3TzXoPTlT2apjrbSMvJak7OpqV5UohSwBCOvtVeJJJCctz+Q/P2pcuKZdFAQeA19SedXYC8WGZjJJOvkcsfSgTx7EA0GSOWdLwMbYihOI4vIpO55DmSdhVtzEAUvcZjmPoOnj51Q24Q5tg1nEXVWM5B1JgAST4xMcvICluNsqzi6xbOIlp1KiZXpHP0FMcQwpddb9+dHhFschGKdpARuW1zIFJIMiT9I6Ggb3Ew1shbaiDRZxK51i2JOTX2pdib3+o+VQB4DnTuKA7FXQts4l8p0+lUYouU1kMASNI2I1H1o69fuSFiAPDn/AIoZcNcumFzMB0EkmfDYeNEyUolMvVGh7Oh8RmuRPw1E/wBzEzl/4nT+qtDaGlddksCcOuQxLS5PMNIEGN9CPY08bDA8qyp5XIQlnqTsynEWEbajUedKDjwjkhYTTNpGW5pEA895Fbq9hFA7oA/fWvnvEkb4QLiSzZmjfvNln0IihXa2l45FNUa3AY455V2yMA0A7FtxBnnJ9ac2eIXAdGVxzkZSP9w09wKw/ZrG5EYuJTRZ/q1GnlTjDoy6qx1PzDcDlRKcURPTxl2h3xzJiLOmpRgxXnCmT56V5wu9IGs/uPypdi+JIyxl78SpHd8JJHjy515wG4QCrRuSImIOvPxmqyybopC0cLimNu0HCVxVh7R3IlT0YbGvk1q49vNbuAhllTO4jp1g6jwnpX2qyZFYjt/wPMTfQAQpz8ttJ9j9POr4peGDxyp0znshfF0EN8yK4PoVYH7/API1u8POUZt4E/58ax/Zvh3wltYiNHdg39jhVVj5Mg/5VtgtWhCnYvqHcuDypXuSpReBemZhGM/h15kCPeKuNnUk6E7kaT4wND51X8MgyEYL0I/Ou0uDlt0NE4fZgQyZMb9raZ2MGTrnYeOUEfSuxgWI/wD2KR/ZH/dVto+JX6qfWr1sONQJ8j9qrsiamPWamly3/P54A14Jm3uH0URWK7T3r2GvNb7pWAwYiCVP+ZFfTLB9D7fSkPbLs6MYiwQtxJgnYg7g8+QP/wB1MHUjX0uscWvUfBksFiFAU/DGYINSecb0o/jHd8qgamNBuf2a3eF7N20Ba62bmRssAe9AAW4N0BVnu2wNlX9epq0sqiamLWQySrHzXkQYDgTXrnw85P8AORzP8o6ARrW64fwhLCZUA8TGp/x4UL2Uw4V4A/8ALn/czAn6RWlvAUrnm2LanO3PauhZ8QKY2NWJezbUtx1svdRVManMf6Y1+uX3p5hrIAAAgUvTBTpIoa2TWG7bBkZVQaEEt6MG+4mvoGJxSW9Nz0Gp8z0HiawnaBbl+7mEQRAXoNhr1JmjY8f9z6QXSSvJz0IbGLy5rZGjMD9iDWgsY023adRC6ciDWd49ZK3FMR/prI6xH11FGcOv/FVEJ7weB4jpRpRvo03UkNrzqXbLtsPIaR7zV+Cu5XHQ6eo1H5/Sspw3jZ2uRv67+xrR4Z1cSp/wfEUvlxSh2hfbxRtMBdkCueMYZblshlzAFWI6hWBI8iAfel3CsTI13G/nTfMCP30ocWZ2WG2RTwmyqNdtLHwwZA5DPqV9DypqBVOEtqqAKABHLqd67N4ePsabSsTlJLllleVScSOh9qlTtBetD5MotwvuxLHqdPrRNuyR81tv36UssAMR+960OFwvX3o1HnsSeT7Z1gzbB0LL4GI/SmgPSg2s/s1zh7oQwTAPqs+B5VRr4NTBPZ7ZBpmuKhxK9a5N4da5Jh5uPhi7tFdy4e4Y07s+RdQfoTSO7ctFbS6QwkaeX/yrRY+0Llt0OzAj9+tYK/jHSyFZDnstBH9O0j6UHLjbNb+mNSi4ruzYWLqo2dYhT3gN8rBRPpAPpTLF39KyVvimYLcQaMIIPI/rrXR4tlAV9ByJ5eB8PGrzwycU0EeP38jXhzzcuE9FHvmJ+w9qZ/Hk5FIB5t08B1NYocay3GS3qXAAI1iCcx+uniKcYK8ugeCAIidNeZbr96rj077ZGeNOh4bYUECGOumpJMaT11jTxrO2bDNeLjKEEzG3dLAfrU43xpJ+BaPfaJ6ovLfZjsOkzQ5cIgto8E+vkB4fpVct1SCafE63fIs7SoSgZl3bKI6Ef4Fd4PswzYZbttiXBBy9Y6f1T9qI4hiJZLchgm/i7fhHU/rW3wlpURUEd0AbR5/WrY+qJ1eqlhjHb3f+j4q+EGcg6MCdDpPoefhT7slw29duAGVUc9QQPzr6Djuz+HvXFuOgLDntPSY3pjbsBRCgAdBR5T3KmDn/AFP2VCPL/wBCW7wl0Oa2cw5jYx9jVmHxWuX8W0c56RToIaWY3EwdSF+rkfkKV9BN2hCeucYfiKwl7SqINw0OzLyzfShVM7CB1J/Pau9Bzny296biqMDJm3O0kv59hCseU1KozkVKuB9dL5M5wt4IB5GD6GPyrXYRhFYC7icty4RIXPnHKVY6+xJp7geMBZzH5efgdvT9KhkYprHk+jWE0o4jey7QZ5HY1weNLMTqBPmOtB3sRbvnKT8NuR/CT0I5VRKhrNnjk4i+QmziM2kEEbqdx/ir1uRXvDLhBFq6oDgd1jqHUdG6+FMjZU/hFW9RDMMdq7F2cGk3H+FG6pe388aj+bw860r4dPKqzaXrVtyDYZzwz3xZ8s4XxArKlZE7ePMetMsRZzLm5N8oBPT6V12n4IwuvctdSY6zrtz386UcN4gwORzlIzb+I108a5vjhnqouOaKmV8OsuHEc5A9CNPrTXG8XFoZZIubDmvntv4Vxi2/hgjAByQSoEfOVAJ8v0pR/EQZym5c3ncA+FCeV3x0Wlji3YZavLZBd4NxtYO+vNj+Vd4O8BNwnvN+InQT/KOtX8J4RdvHO1qeYz6L5xzrW4Hs8in4lyHcbaDKvkOfnQ55Y0dLNGID2f4aDeW5lhVBYTuTEAmfFiR5TWsJqnDWdz1+w/zNX5RV8SqNs8zrcjy5W/jgHfEEbGukxzda7NhTVOKCW0LNsP2BRfaK+5K7OcXxBo+YIvM7sfBR+dK2xij5Fj+pu8310FDXUZv9S4coPyjmR/SOniapz6EgQo0/Z51FIzs2ecn/AC//AAaYUNcPXqTTG3h6p4aIQLzOre2g9tfWmyLUXRfDp1Lt8+f3F7WTXlM1yjepUb2H/wCDB9yPm12D3SPmBH+KEtMy5cw/9NvEHVTTK3aDyOeh8/8APP0q7E4E/DcR8yyp6OhzD7EetXTMyEb4AlusigMAdQA3PKSQCD47HxHhRNjEAgowkA7j5hI3HUHp4ULjb5uKmUd24oYrEw5kNkPISu3lXeBxCskmM+kN4jdT5jUeXjXNBHDazQ8Nx0Zbdwhk/wDLflI5dR++VN7l4ikv8MAgugZrLj/UXmh5keRmnljBHKO/m6GNxyqqaNHCpuNA7Yk1WcSaIu4B/A0Few7DcUSNMmUJoC4jeAzMxAEA+HP9KwvFrvxrqBUKyZB/F4eXXWtH2hJJCN8sZj4hZ0+tCdl8A9y6106iCB4Tp9tPehyqCbZ6rQqtNGb+BLdwDIyvc1zTAG2u2nt/yFbTsh8K6gy2wrAxtzjx/ehoviPCcy7CR12IjY0t7O2btq4ZAEESOoDaN7EiaS3KUafYac9+N0+TWDCxXRXSjnWaHdKFJGaptiq3xHQafXxrsY8dKKt4FDMrzPXnr+/Kr0wVsfhH1rSU4VwZMoZNz5ABjR0NCcRxqCGIJYfKp2n+YinGJW3bUswAAFZC4jXWLnuqZbyQaTH0HU1NpiuplKCryU3bzO0klmP7gVeH0HNE9mY/qfoK9s2ydVXV5W2Oi83J+k+fSj7eCDOLY+S38x/muEfbauEY45Pk84XiSCS3qfE1obd3uydB96Bs4SympEx1+pPUmk2L4o9x+7MHRBzjr+/GuYdXgV3bfgd4rGAc6lZfEOxJ70xueU+FSpFJZMjdlFq5BHhTC9j84yxry/uG3vt60ty6wfH6VGYn6VxROuQW8gtvBkKGDDqLd2NR4owFXvZALvlEBouoPwuPxr/Sw1HQ0ZjcObyqxGsFW/tbf1Bg+9D2yQUuMP8A0bw5EfKD9vQ0ZwtDrhaNJwJ2VCJlZ9J2PvAPrTDDXcgyrtyHTwHhSbCXcihZ209BoPWAB6UauJqrxDMJOKqxmMaele/xIO4petzwqZ/SqPGgqyy8iPtdhFZxlECBMablv0FH9nMN8O0o57n1/QQPSvMdqwBM93/u/wA0dgV7tJ52/wAp6HBkvSxLv4oZ1U/iMDz5V1i+GBoI3H2O4oa9g2d0j8LKx/2sD+VPDQEBnLa1R5XLiujVbvUsCim82USOX2qn+Jbwq67S1riqSpO2on+UzGvhBHpR9PNXtYvqYNVKIPxcvcZV5chyZo3PgoE+MxVAwxY/CmQCGut1PJPIDlyo1wJnpp+v2FUs4Uaac/WnNiMuUVdsLsFEJOWSYE9ANlA5AV0uJtjQLHl40rS/m5GuMUYgiY10NQ3BUS8qStdBfFMShSNcv4upHJR5mPQVn2vHXkTv5dB0FFIc7hSdKK4naQKMtc68CObJvdoTHSvaiIWJgTXtRQvUvAXxXCFLh6NBB86ERJMbfvatVjLAuIROvInkeVJRg5d7Z0JUOvnzH1PtXcjmbT1LjydcIRnDKPw6+h/f1q29w99cyfNA850+woThV427oO2sMPAmPoYrVtqVM6LJ9Yj8zUubDYIqeNfKM9h8OTeW0waYzR/SDBM7b01v4PKoPScx28jHSKIwVlQpj5CzMJ/qYsT4CSY8DSXirYi/cCWjltKyjMDuCNcwJ1APKh7pbuA3pxxxddvovtXwQCdJ2HM8pijkw7dKAwyBSAL4LARokTrqNadWLgA2/fOKj1HdFcK3cSE2MWLnkqiPc/pRuEbSvn/Fr7Z7mJS6yuZOhzI2uilTpptV/De0eOCBvh2bgM8yjaEjUTB25VOXRZW9yPQYs0I4lD4PpVnWia+dYTtZxF3NtMJbLRmjUmJ65wKd4rj+KyBf4Vrd54ClyuQndohp2B3pWWGUXTBSd8mjvXYoP4/MkAdSY+tIxg+IXY+JdW2OYVST9F/Or7HZeyTN+7cuHocyr9p9zU+ivLOWVJcI7xvaSyD8O3/q3DGi7akCSee/KiMDwlmOe/vIOXxB0kbADpSrtOmFtIgt/DRwwgCMxB0M89AZk9KDv9pXv9wE21EAx876a6j5V+tFWFJXEDKb8j9VUllUzlYgRrvqB7GPSr72AXKWOsASCJ1oHhDBYOWNMseHL2P3NMLFguTnEKoIUKSDDc96s8n9onKMW6rsEshQ6d7JroAJnz6CqeLMDIQAnbu/zztVGJ4cLDIbXxLmYkZHho0JLkkTpA0Ma0Tgx/ouoEOSRJ1jQCfPeoUtnLfAo7jcGJEBJCLuTqdpJ/KjeILbM98jJ3cqiWJHhzrsWUs25JAuAyv9Q5AD0n60kxeOCfIczMD39d23+GBq/nt0qzW9ppiihx7i6219flVLYPO6wDH05VKQ3beX5kBY8mJLeZVSMvqZqU0qCKSXg+hYHDXB810Op201/wCU1Xj7ai4mozCT5rzHnv7GluCv3bdxrYT4YSGus5DqFicwWQdYOxNdXrVy6VYkhXYHYZhoYCzvC78pJoF0MuX4fRMY6HLcRsp1nn3PlzsNh6+FaM5WtAAqywAGn5ssaaeVZ7FcIR0RU0BuArzzIsyxJ3mZnyo25hCGFu33Qq5hyBJ5/SKiREZuF8XZbduZ3yMSx5KBA9etWcStMgzI0AR3Y8pr23gswBf54IMH8/ahrtnEOj52PdfuKv4kXQFo3J1PpXOy1e1uS76PMQbZXOYExDQYDRoDG9U8T44bGHZ2y54hSuxY/KdfemS4dVtZcragmIzd7Lv0B8KyPa/hty6loIrSJlW7smIEcp0OhjnG1WwqO73BtPiW9fZgBnMhHMEglZ31mmOF4rctKqG2GAn8RB1YnUR40FcRVaLiFGHmrD0om1cAGozj+YfN69a138o0Zh/D+0ot31um28AQQr7kTE6iRqdDTbifbVLuX4dt8yt8QZ2mDlKwP5R/msY10AkxI/e4NG4DEWs4Mxp/LFLZMEZO2Vbo03/5xfaV+HaAaSZZ23JnX1NXWe19/Ooi2RqJCtpt1O2lZtySRkUnfUnT2ozDYTncu7/+Wg1Pgaq8MF4AuTHWIy3mN28wZjA0AGg2Gn5k1V8S1b7ywuWdNyQd69W1YtxnUDTRSZb1A2orD4W5dE2rS2kI+fJqR4Tv6ChTqKBq5MKw3E8vyj/c2g86ZW+KOoJ0IG53kco9NPMUFhOBFNSzO0fMRH/U+3otE3rLFlBGwmQxPQEbDTUH3pPfBypE59Pk9NyXFHmF4tmvAurguGIXQaAjWAfOisRdV+6JjZoHeAJBbQaGYiaCW1qSIJEgAamDE178MqTDQQJAnWKvKKSMvfJLk74jiUYQqa6y75QAoGuadxqIWs1iLRRZtIypOQ3WEu7dFj5V5wOXPlR3FcaWgFZkAZR8zxMu3ReQ66034Nxa3btuSuUqpgg91simSV2UgiIHWujcVwdFqUqk6Mxw62bTsWXNpHTfWdfKvK9GEu3giLq5BusTyVmhR92/3VKLyDUZfJo7mL+NcCl2KE5nBVVlVMrbBGpE7+A8avx1xSTrqx0Osqv4o+wFB2rItL+HN9STyFe3LLfO0SdgDtUOCrkcaah7uw27eJU5T3tFAH4V5D6amrbGIyFmeS2xA7wjkfCgreHuRtAPiAa5CAGGIA5QR9apt+ADclUh3a4nagZyqZ8yg8tFkgn0oIX0+LnUOLeneA7u2ojpQeIKPlEK2U6A6j5Su3PQ0fh7oKZYCgCCNhEfaonHbyEnNySXx5OPhm5ebK5Xmp1MjSjPh5pk5uXmBpMeJk+tAm4DpbuAZdIGu+lNLC8umlLZW6S+TQ/pkFcsjEvFOzVq8DoBPhI9By9KxHGOyd2wZtHu8gdvf9a+slKGxViRRcWqyQrm0abjGR8KxyOp7yFW+/psaosX4IPSvqvFeGK0gga+AIMdQRrWS4v2bVQWTT7e51X6itXFqoTVdM54JL7M8+PcmBTjhFu62iws6FuY8J6+WtThfZi43w3bUOGIA3hGCyx5AmfavpPAuDraAMLPIAaKOg/XnS+o1cYcLlgFh3P6F/Auy6oc7rLdW39FP3NahMOBsNtOunmavRKsC1k5MksjtsIlGPQM1ulHHHyKGCB9wQWCADeSx8qfuKV8Qwy3MqnbNMROytprVcfE0U1DcsMl9C60mmZQBIDW9ZkdZ5g0FfxKhC7LliYUGSxO3iNftTwvaOa0p3EKuXROTBemw8NKQ8S4ebZBSCTCpJHzmR9Br6VoRowMmNRrbyhLirpUMPmvPAdhqEESFTqwEa8qtwzq8awGOUA7BFEuSOUlvpVuIwnwnKBtVBE66sV7xnzdR6UywvCUCSQGEBUM6qNQJB0AckmaJJoG8duirhzMjSBmLLyMd0GFk+Q+tSmQgznJQEn5dBmWAR5fpUoPqFEn8gd5RO8nr+nQVXbGu8UOztyB+1VHEt4U4oquRtNdyGQeT67nWi8RjvhWyyoGbQKoXdiYG3KleHxfWrlxb8tvLU+Qobgl2UjJR77Y7stcYAlASILfCdSIK/yt0M6TQyMl1nBGhBEg5TtuV2NL8NjjldT3QY0UQN99NzRODuoQO6ysARMaGRQNjJlPdSXXn7DMNYtgIFhmUasOe4H5+1NMMtKuGCVzECWPLTQaD7T605sikckt07N7BDZhSotiqbtWmh7zVKCR7FmNtzS1MF8R1Tkd/wC0b/p602vUTwiwAC5GraD+0fqdfaiQ7GMuX08b+TnGoAUAAAAaI8Coq3DVxxKMyRzD/wDbXeFoWX8wtif4SDEFWRURa6qoNspegMQ8MPI/l+tMLlI+K3GDqROx25zFdFOUkkUzy24ZMq+LdW4IbNPXaJ5/4rjHY0M4JSIBAOxg7nx2j1Nd4lLqic6x3eUHXlEb61n+KDEswXOCGzHKggKAN8x1k6CtDHByRhNSimuQ3BLDNcdZmQJgxJPej1Jo2xcW3qFzKyqrSdwCZ06maVcNxGoW4uUsoYEEwdACB46jTqD4Uyt2gdVPoRppV3DwQt3jsLF61GS4/c3Rj02yn+ofUVK9sKjDKwgjdTy8R71KrS+Qykvr/AmF3w+1VXSv8uv73pqcCjGLbMAPmYwRpyXTU+PKq8fgFtLmFxcvMPoT5NzNNPLFl5JtdCjxAk+A0o3h3CGuqTquoCmJU9Z5/wCaqt3Huvlt91Ds7LJI8F2HrVlhLtq46pmdsuveBJBjUAwo9KpNprhg1GDdvlAd4sjsjA6aaiPoddq6wWKJlcwn8IEncwJPWTVj4Utmzh1blnB28WEgHbnTDBcKW3l75aNdY5bajzFdPKlFv6L4MbyZEkuBvgrUQBsBHtTNRQuESjDWMuTfyPkrc0Jear7rUG5k1ey8F5B8SdPPT9T6D8q4biAXQSB50PjLpzGNhp+vuftQ2Jw7qAzKQDtP6VpYcVRTfbMvWZHkl7fAauKzuu+zb+Q/SmuD3rOcPb/UHk32rR4Pek9XHblr6G9L+iMVr01Fr00uR5KXrNcYxBS/mYv8NUJOVSRI1kvy3GlaNzS7FWGdCoCw05swJ0Ph5RRMC91gdX+lQHicQ1+0rBBBGbvLLcipBjQxSm7ZvJ3oOUb5oI9I1G9NrfHMiqsKxJy6ECBoASBtTHEYkNoLZuajQDSQZ1YwKbx3Ay0oz53cmaxtm4UnIwYarALCRrGnI7VZhCWytbhjGsnUTyIGvL6U6xGNvquYi1bUfzEufZfypNw29YNxrdwiWOe2yhkgue8s8u9B1071EeS+WiJxhuXP/Q1ewCoLgeGuvt0qV6j3BOXLfA0kEK4PRuRqVXdYW4fB1dx8k28OiEjQsQBaTw0+Zh/KPUigLGABuO926GZdEYgRBGsJsBrHWr89oKFUZQNgI0oS8y8iavHEFlFSqym24svYhgS+cXNTlAGo+hPtTC5jbAm6sfEgLBmIDamkzivIqXj/AHF1uiqig7H4m49xFW4LaEPmdORgZTB1Bn86Y4JWKrmYMwEFhME9YO3KR1pErCtFw63CL5T760DVVGCSZoaFXJyGNgRVjmuFqu69IWPVbB71yvMNan9+5/fWqnEn97daoHF0GwPh5cv19aNgxvI+C2fIoQpeQ98Cg5kVRe4crb3GPnr96D4gbjoCwGQwRqPTSgFvMBAY+9aEIz+TLr3VXAzfhgQqwadY9wRTDCUjsXGLKCxPeGlPsOKS1Sanyx/BSx0HKajGvErxzS5HkGxFzKrHoCfYGlQxLqAOnhRXGsQEtEnmyj2OY/RaRXOJqeUesU9o8ftcmhTWTppBlywrASqKoOZoUAt4E9Kvw3EFtWjALhJOgJY5mMAD1pIMSXmAxA3gE+9c2cXBmabeC3wIVJPdENs8ZW+5F+yUCOqgTIBcGPiDTXSP91d8SwFtluXUOYqwcgRooHfVfMSR4gV5ZvLcBVUktq0DUkRqfaurSgNmiIIiPDcGetCljafBSSk+1YTcNrD5HtnRliMwGYEhg0n1968oGxw5SXUakEFZOnwyNBHUGR6CpVNpV+pftXH8+gs4EfzfSuTgx1qVKZsdTOWw6jlSvE4jKYCr617UokOS5R/FsdIUSQNupitpYqVKQ/qP5o/sO6X8rC6GvVKlZzGIdgOIPdg7Mcp8gJj10rm1w62wnX3/AMVKlP6V1j4+RLWP8QrxOBRRIn3oErUqU7B8C6YRg7UsD0I+9PLVSpWfrPzoc035X+4Wlc3KlSlGFXZnO1hJFpeXfb1GVR9zWYuLFe1K3tF+ijN1P6jLMFxG7Zn4blZ30BmPMVRdvMzFmMk6n9ipUppRV2Bb4C8HiXT5WKzvBInzpraYxvNSpQsiXYFtlLY8g/KDyqVKlU2oImz/2Q==" style="width: 122px; height: 186px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" title="">
```

null

Answer (score 0):

After some research and a series of other articles on StackOverflow, I determined that base64 images need to be handle as such:

Isolate the base64 image string. In my case, I did this with the following regex:

```
var b64Reg = /base64,(.*?)"/ig;
if (matches = b64Reg.exec(data))
{       
    b64Img = matches[1];
    // ajax function call here
}
```

On the PHP side, there are a number of helpful posts, but this is the one I used: [How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)