# how to save base64 image server side

Tags: php, server-side

how can i save image server side i have this code but for some reason the image that i upload to the server is saved as text/x-generic. what can i do to fix this?

```html
<?php

  function base64_to_image($base64_string) {

      $data = explode(',', $base64_string);
      $ext = "";
      switch ($data[0]) {
          case "data:image/png;base64";
              $ext = "png";
              break;
          case "data:image/jpg;base64";
              $ext = "jpg";
              break;
          case "data:image/jpeg;base64";
              $ext = "jpg";
              break;
          case "data:image/gif;base64";
              $ext = "gif";
              break;
      }

      $milli = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

      $output_file = "img/" . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . "." . $milli . "." . $ext; 
      $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

    
      fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
      fclose($ifp); 

      return $ifp; 

  }

  $file = base64_to_image($_POST['file']);
  var_dump($file);
?>
```

Comment: umm, where did you find `text/x-generic` ?

Comment: Type text/x-generic

Comment: hmm, weird, you did include the `b` in `fopen($output_file, "wb");`. although i'm a bit concerned with the `:` in the file name as defined in `"img/" . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s')`, but i don't think it could affect the output. anyway, does the file shows properly as image when downloaded?

Comment: the file is empty no image or anything is shown

Comment: the size is 0 byte

Comment: Chack that `base64_decode` returns a non FALSE value (FALSE means incorrect base64 codification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this function to save base64 image and it's working fine. Try this-

```
function saveBase64ImagePng($base64Image, $imageDir)
{
    //set name of the image file

    $fileName =  'test.png';

    $base64Image = trim($base64Image);
    $base64Image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64Image);
    $base64Image = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $base64Image);
    $base64Image = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64Image);
    $base64Image = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $base64Image);
    $base64Image = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64Image);

    $imageData = base64_decode($base64Image);
    //Set image whole path here 
    $filePath = $imageDir . $fileName;


   file_put_contents($filePath, $imageData);


}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: where would the folder name be?

Comment: $imageDir, you can set your file path here.

Comment: try this edited one, earlier was including the logic of thumbnail cutting as well

Comment: You need to test remove, this metadata string 'data:image/png;base64,' from your base64 url. And validate your base64 string that you are receiving at server here - http://base64-encoding.online-domain-tools.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string

Comment: where would the folder name be ?

Comment: $imageDir will be the path/folder name where you would like to store image.