# Base 64 Image String Convert and Upload To the PHP server

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I Have Image String Like

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data); // Decode image using base64_decode
$file = uniqid() . '.jpg'; 


//Now you can put this image data to your desired file using file_put_contents function like below:
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

I wanted To convert Into Image and Upload To the Server

The Upload Folder Like

```
www.abc.com/uploads
```

And My File is

```
Www.abc.com/webservices/index.php (In this file I will write the code)
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: What have you done before asking us? Have you code that you tried to use but didn't work? We are here to answer questions, not to just write code for someone who is too lazy to do it themselves.

Comment: Yes I have tried my code is not working

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it,

```
function writePng($data, $filename){
    $bin = substr($data, strlen('data:image/png;base64,'));
    $bin=base64_decode($bin);
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w+');
    fwrite($fp, $bin);
    fclose($fp);
}
writePng($data, '1.png');
```