# Ionic upload base64 image using $http

Tags: angularjs, http, post, ionic-framework

**My server-side code already works using postman, it doesn't work using Ionic**

I'm trying to upload a image converted in base64 (about 2M) to a server using this function:

```
this.postPic = function(image,tags,title){
    var dfd = $q.defer();
    var req = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: baseURL+"utility.uploadpic",
          data: "auth_token="+$localstorage.get("token")+"&tags="+tags+"&title="+title+"&base64_file="+image,
          headers:{
              'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
    };
    $http(req).success(function(response){
      dfd.resolve(response);
    });
    return dfd.promise;
  }
```

It gives me an error during upload ( showing me the message "Error creating file" in the following code)

```
function upload_pic($title,$tags,$base64_file){
        $title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $desc = $title;
        $file_obj_string = base64_decode($base64_file);
        //Creating file from string
        $imgRaw = imagecreatefromstring( $file_obj_string);
        if ($imgRaw !== false) {
        .................
        }
        else{
            return "Error creating file";
        }
```

I don't know if it couldn't create the image from string because there is a size problem or something else.
Any idea?

Comment: Hope this question help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string

Comment: My server-side code already works using postman, it doesn't work using Ionic

Comment: ok got it. print your data using print_r($_POST) and check whole base64 string comes or they cut

Comment: All the content is sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I just had to replace all spaces (I do not know where they were created) with +

```
$base64_file = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_file);
```

I hope this is helpful for somebody :)