# How to save onpaste image with a src of "data:image/png;base64,..." using php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image

I'm trying to save the pasted image into a folder and the relevant details to the database, but my current code is not saving the pasted image, I try to put a hard coded url on the src attribute and it was working.

I inspect element of the src of the pasted image and it was very long, like this *"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARIAAAC4CAYAAAAvx2MfAAAgAElEQVR4Ae2dCXwW1dX..."* its longer than this but for sample purposes. How should I save the image using this image address? Please help.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <input class="form-control" id="pasteArea" placeholder="Paste image here..."></input>
      <img name="map-sketch" id="pastedImage" width="100%" height="100%" src='images/sample.png'></img>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Save</button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" id="saving-info"></div>
```

The src of the image above is a hard coded url.

Here is the javascript onpaste that I'm using:

```
document.getElementById('pasteArea').onpaste = function (event) {
   var items = (event.clipboardData  || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
   console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types

   var blob = null;
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
         blob = items[i].getAsFile();
      }
   }

   if (blob !== null) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
         console.log(event.target.result); // data url!
         document.getElementById("pastedImage").src = event.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
   } 
}
```

And here is the AJAX code:

```
function save(){
   var params = 'kind=land';
   var image = document.getElementById("pastedImage").getAttribute("src");
   params += '&image='+image;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("saving-info").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }else { // waiting for result 
            document.getElementById('saving-info').innerHTML = '<img src="../images/ajax_loader.gif">';
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../functions/save-faas.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

And here is the PHP code for saving the image:

```
<?php
   $url = $image;
   $img = '../images/1.png';
   file_put_contents($img,file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

The code here is working with hard coded URL but not for pasted image.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string

Comment: Hello @Zaid, the solutions in that link works perfect for me. Thank you

Comment: You very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

how about using onchange on this `pasteArea` id?

```
$("#pasteArea").onchange(function(){
//do something
});
```