# How to save Data Url like save $_FILES in php

Tags: php, todataurl

How to save DATA URL like save $_FILES in php?

my code is:

```
$dataurl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAB...."

$image_content = base64_decode(str_replace("#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i","", $dataurl)); // remove "data:image/png;base64,"
$tempfile = tmpfile(); // create temporary file
$filesize = fwrite($tempfile, $image_content); // fill data to temporary file
$metaDatas = stream_get_meta_data($tempfile);
$tmpFilename = $metaDatas['uri'];

$file = array(
    'name' => 'MyFile.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'tmp_name' => $tmpFilename,
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => $filesize,
);

move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $location);
```

The problem maybe in `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $location);`

Comment: I am unable to see any `move_uploaded_file()` in your given code

Comment: @AlivetoDie you can look again

Comment: @AlivetoDie `move_uploaded_file` is a native PHP function, it is just used wrong here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string

Answer (score 0):

Read the description in PHP guide for [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) before using this function.

The important part is (qoute from the description):

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (**meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism**). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.

The file you created was NOT uploaded via PHP HTTP POST upload mechanism, it was a temporary file you have created yourself, so you can not move it with this function.

If the data arrives as a Base64 encoded string, you can just write the file directly to the desired location. The `move_uploaded_file` function is ONLY for files uploads, and Base64 strings sent in the body are not files.

Comment: how I can upload base64 to my server?

Comment: @RobbyAlamsyahRamadhan   please try once my answer. Also you can refer to the link also if mine not worked.Let me know also that problem solved or not?