# Amazon S3 hosted images not rendering in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, mime-types, content-type

We're uploading images to an amazon s3 bucket via Laravel with the following conditions:

```
$fileOptions = [
  'visibility' => 'public',
  'ContentType' => 'image/png',
  'ContentTransferEncoding' => 'base64'
  //'ContentType' => 'binary/octet-stream'
];

$this->lastUploadSuccess = Storage::disk($this->useDisk)
->getDriver()
->put( $_filePath.(strrpos($_filePath, "/")!=strlen($_filePath)-1?"/":"").$_fileName , $_fileContents , $fileOptions);
```

The upload itself works fine and the file is present and public but when trying to access it in a browser at the returned URL it's unable to render the file.

Inspector suggests it IS being sent with the file type that was set on upload

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 22290
Server: AmazonS3
```

Saving the file to the local computer and trying to open it there also returns OS specific flavours of

```
the file "filename.png" could not be opened    
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

Opening it in a text editor indicates it IS the data that's being uploaded at $_fileContents (ie, the base64 or octet-stream) and no combination of ContentType and ContentTransferEncoding seems to get the image to render or download into a proper image file.

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: The answer here worked for us: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string/11511605#11511605](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string/11511605#11511605)