# How to forward POST request with adding file parameters in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to forward a POST request in Symfony but before forwarding I need to convert an image from base64 to $_FILES parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you submitting a form before you forward?
If you are you can do:

```
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid){
    //Do whatever work you need to in here like uploading the image 
    // before the forward
    return $this->forward('@Bundle:action', array(
       'request' => $request));
}
```

As for converting your file take a look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string) question. It should do the trick. Hope this helps!

Comment: The idea is to add the uploaded (converted from base64) image to the $_FILES before forward. Or to the $request->files because in the forwarded controller I need it as if it was submitted via POST from the browser.

Comment: So you should then be able to do `$request->files->add($arrayWithImageInIt)`