# Intervention Image + Laravel's File Storage: Store resized/decoded base64 image (Intervention Image encode() doesn't work)

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, laravel-storage

- I am using [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) jQuery plugin which returns the cropped image **encoded in base64**.
- After submitting the form (with the cropped image **encoded in base64**) - I decode & resize it using the [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) library:

  ```
  public function decodeResizeAndStore(Request $request)
  {
      $croppie_code = $request->croppie_code;

      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511605/4437206
      if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $croppie_code, $type)) {
          $encoded_base64_image = substr($croppie_code, strpos($croppie_code, ',') + 1);
          $type = strtolower($type[1]);

          $decoded_image = base64_decode($encoded_base64_image);

          $resized_image = Image::make($decoded_image)->resize(300, 200);

          // AND NOW I WANT TO STORE $resized_image using Laravel filesystem BUT...
      }
  }
  ```

Finally, I want to store the resized image using [Laravel's filesytem (File Storage)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem) and that's where I'm stuck - when I try this:

```
Storage::put($path, (string) $resized_image->encode());
```

... it doesn't work. Actually, it is working something - it looks like there is some memory leak or something, the browser's tab freezes, my RAM & CPU usage go high...

So I just tried:

```
dd($resized_image->encode());
```

... and yes, this is where it definitely crashes - when using [encode()](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode) method.

I am not sure why, maybe this is happening because I'm not working with a standard image upload but with decoded base64?

But, on the other side, Intervention Image can create a new image instance from the base64 as well as from the decoded base64: http://image.intervention.io/api/make 
... and, in my case, this works OK:

```
$resized_image = Image::make($decoded_image)->resize(300, 200);
```

I could then use the [save()](http://image.intervention.io/api/save) method and everything would work OK. But I need to use [Laravel's File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem).

Do you know how I can handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using latest version of Laravel ([5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances)):

you can use [stream](http://image.intervention.io/api/stream) method like so:

```php
// use jpg format and quality of 100
$resized_image = Image::make($decoded_image)->resize(300, 200)->stream('jpg', 100);
// then use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage
Storage::disk('your_disk')->put('path/to/image.jpg', $resized_image); // check return for success and failure
```