# How to get canvas edited image data to HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, canvas

```
<canvas id="c" name="c"></canvas>
<input style="display:none;" type="file" name="nextImage" id="nextImage"/>
```

Above code is canvas where edited image is placed, below is input field where i want the canvas image value.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

  jQuery('#svconvac').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Click");
      var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    //jQuery("#nextImage").val(dataURL);

    console.log(dataURL);
    //return false;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "editMap.php",
      data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL
      },
      success: function(data) {
        data['dataURL'] = document.getElementById("nextImage").value;
        console.log('saved'); 
      } 
    });


  });

});
```

So far what i tried using this ajax function but no chances to be successful, am i calling wrong data in ajax? where it says:

```
editedMap = $data['dataURL'];
```

My Function for saving to database Please also look at this:

```
public function mapUpdate($data, $file, $id)
        {
            $floor_name =$this->fm->validation($data['floor_name']);

            $floor_name =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['floor_name']);

            $permited  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
            $file_name = $file['nextImage']['name'];
            $file_size = $file['nextImage']['size'];
            $file_temp = $file['nextImage']['tmp_name'];

            $div = explode('.', $file_name);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
            $unique_image = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
            $uploaded_image = "uploads/maps/".$unique_image;

            if($floor_name == '')
            {
                $msg = "<span class='error'> Fields must not be empty !! </span>";
                return $msg;
            }
            else{
                if (!empty($file_name)) 
                {

                    if ($file_size >1048567) 
                    {
                        echo "<span class='error'>Image Size should be less then 1MB! </span>";
                    } 

                    elseif (in_array($file_ext, $permited) === false) 
                    {
                        echo "<span class='error'>You can upload only:-".implode(', ', $permited)."</span>";
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        $delImageQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_map WHERE mapId='$id'";
                        $getData = $this->db->select($delImageQuery);

                        if ($getData) 
                        {
                            while ($delImg =$getData->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                                $delLink =  $delImg['mapImg'];
                                unlink($delLink);
                            }
                        }


                        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);

                        $query= "UPDATE tbl_map SET floorName = '$floor_name', mapImg = '$uploaded_image' WHERE mapId ='$id' ";

                        $update_row =$this->db->update($query);
                        if($update_row)
                        {
                            $msg ="<span class='success'> Map Update successfully. </span>";
                            return $msg;
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<span class='error'>Map Not Update !</span>";
                        }
                    }

                } 

                else
                {                               
                    $query= "UPDATE tbl_map SET floorName = '$floor_name' WHERE mapId ='$id' ";

                    $update_row =$this->db->update($query);

                    if($update_row)
                    {
                        $msg ="<span class='success'> Map Update successfully. </span>";
                        return $msg;
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        echo "<span class='error'>Map Not Update !</span>";
                    }
                }
            }
   }// Update function ends here
```

Hoping for some help.

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of the screenshots.

Comment: done please check.

Answer (score 0):

Input type file does not accept base64 data as value, you can use input type hidden like below.

HTML

```html
<canvas id="c" name="c"></canvas>
<input type="hidden" name="nextImage" id="nextImage">
```

JS

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

  jQuery('#svconvac').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Click");
      var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    //jQuery("#nextImage").val(dataURL);

    console.log(dataURL);
    //return false;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "editMap.php",
      data: { // [1]
        imgBase64: dataURL
      },
      success: function(data) { // [2]
        // data at [1] and [2] are not same, data [2] is variable that hold values of response from "editMap.php" API, you may also change this name to any name like response.
        data['dataURL'] = document.getElementById("nextImage").value;
        console.log('saved'); 
      } 
    });


  });

});
```

Comment: Not working for me, I attached my form can you please also look at this?

Comment: i solved it with ajax, can you please check is it right way of storing ajax data to variable :

success: function(data) {
        data.dataURL = document.getElementById("nextImage").value;
        console.log('saved');
      }

Comment: what do you want to achieve? please explain. It is better to add you code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i have variable in ajax called ( dataURL ) and i want that variable data should be place to my input file called ( nextImage ). That's it.

What i tried is:
data.dataURL = document.getElementById("nextImage").value;

Din't worked.

Comment: try like this, 
document.getElementById("nextImage").value = editedMap, 
You can not add string value in input type file, you need to change it to hidden or text

Comment: didn't work. can you check my JS code i have updated.

Comment: what is data['dataURL'] in success function? it means you are updating server (editMap.php) response value. data['dataURL'] will will get valuue of this input field   document.getElementById("nextImage").value

Comment: if i change file type to text or hidden then i can't save that image inside my save function where i'm getting image like this see: 

$file_name = $file['nextImage']['name'];
$file_size = $file['nextImage']['size'];
$file_temp = $file['nextImage']['tmp_name'];

Comment: i have added my function as well check my question.

Comment: remember canvas.toDataURL("image/png") return base64 data (string data) you can get this data in server side as a string and create a file with this data to store in server directory Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511605/9009397

Comment: in my case now i have to replace dataURL with ref url u sent?

Comment: i have sent ref url to convert your base64 string into image file.

Comment: is there any chance for you to check it via anydesk or teamviewer

Comment: no, I've already add enough code, descriptions and links, Please follow link to convert base64 data to image in server side. This is not a big issue. Are you beginner in php and javascript?