# How to convert data:image/webp,base64 in expo (or php)

Tags: php, react-native, base64, expo, webp

So I have this problem where I'm receiving a webp,base64 image format from an api, The image does not show in ios devices but it appears in Android. So is there a solution for those who use expo and want to display webp images on ios?
And I can take another solution if it works in php since that is what I'm using as a backend.

**an example of the returned string of the image**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1yHv.png

Answer (score 0):

Normally webp images are not compatible with Safari. You can check the compatibility for webp [here](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=webp).

What you would need to do is maybe use a service that converts the image to a working format, be it jpeg or png and use a `<picture>` tag. This is just an example of how to use the tag.

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="images/logo@1x.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="images/logo@1x.png" type="image/png">
    <img src="images/logo@1x.png" alt="Logo">
</picture>
```

**UPDATE**

The above example was just to show you how to use the `picture` tag with different types of images.

As for the `base64` images you could do something like this:

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="data:image/webp;base64,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" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
</picture>
```

Another option could be to use Modernizr to detect if the client's browser can use webp. You can check and build a Modernizr specifically for webp detection. Check it [here](https://modernizr.com/download?webp-webpalpha-webpanimation-webplossless_webp_lossless-setclasses).

What you would need to do if you have control over how the images are created/uploaded is to have a jpg/png and a webp version, and just use the corresponding versions as necessary. You do need to have both, because as I said before webp is still not compatible with every browser.

If you run the snippet you'll see that if you try to download the image it will use the webp version. If you open it from Safari it would download the jpg version.

**UPDATE 2: Image conversion**

As for the image conversion, what you could do is either make an image generating function that receives a webp image as a parameter and returns a jpg image.

Since you receive the image in a base64 format, you could use [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511605/1169686) to save the image on your server, but in a .webp format in your case. Afterwards you could use the [imagecreatefromwebp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwebp.php) function to create a new image. Check the example at the end of that page. It converts a webp image to a jpeg.

From what I see you could do something like:

1. Get your API call that contains information on the image.
2. Check if your image exists on your server (the ideal is to create a specific folder and use the same image name).
3. If it exists, you return the path to the image.
4. If it doesn't exist, you create a .webp file from the base64 data. Then you convert it to a .jpg or a .png file depending on your needs.
5. You use the local image. That might also speed up your calls.

Comment: Can you please check the picture that I just added to the post? the syntax you used as a source looks different from what I received

Comment: Yeah this looks more relatable to my problem, but I'm wondering how did you do the converting from webp to png and jpeg? And I'm using react native so I do not have the picture tag.

Comment: Oh, well you'd have to do the conversion probably server-side. What are you building? Also, does the API handle an image format option?

Comment: I'm using php as server-side scripting, and the only format that I can get from the API(serpapi) is webp.

Comment: @NjoodAdel I added some more info on how it could work.