# How to insert canvas image into the database after i converting to base64

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, file, canvas

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("input1").value=canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

codetreatment.php

```
 $data = $_POST["input1"];
    $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
    $data = str_replace(' ','+',$data);

    $data = base64_decode($data);
```

php:

```
    <form action="codetreatment.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" >
     <button  type="submit" name="treatmenthistoryupdatebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

But this code for database didn't work.

What is the next step after converting the canvas image to base64 string? I want to save to the database

Comment: Why  can't you just save it as base64 string as it  is?

Comment: because of the size of base64 is so big

Comment: May be than store it on the file system and store file path instead.

Comment: what is your suggestion to save canvas image to the database? Sorry, sir, I'm a newbie here and just a student

Comment: Sir diphen how to do that?

Comment: There are already few answers on SO, you can search for that. One that I could find is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string

Comment: Make sure the database table accepts BLOB type

Comment: sir ahmad can I ask a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATABASE

```
$data = $_POST["input1"];       
$data = explode(",", $data)[1];
$decoded_image = base64_decode($data);
$temp_name = 'http://your-domain.com/folder/'.md5(time().rand().time()).".png";
file_put_contents($temp_name, $decoded_image);
// Store this $file to table.
$file = basename($temp_name);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208830/discussion-on-answer-by-sumeet-amipara-how-to-insert-canvas-image-into-the-datab).