# Merge with opentbs a field type image data:image/png;base64

Tags: image, merge, base64, cpu-word, opentbs

i am using Opentbs of tinybutstrong.
I have a field type image data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA.... 
I need merge it with Msword. 
What is way correct for do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can [save your base64 image to a png file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string). then merge it with OpenTBS using parameter [ope=changepic](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#pic).

Your can delete the file after the merging.

Comment: Hi, i saved my string as image first. and it works fine.
Now have other question.
If i merge my picture with [onshow.x_picture;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;adjust;unique] workfine.
But if i merge with mergeblok: 
[d.firma;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;adjust;unique]
it show nothing. (can't show image).

Comment: First check the value you’ve got for the field [d.firma]. And also if the block 'b' has several rows, you should not use parameter 'unique', because the picture is not unique then.