# Javascript : Getting the dom image data source and save it to directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an image data here from my console came from DOM displaying it using array

The console data look like this, I perfectly getting this data my problem is how to pass and get that image data into php

```
["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAuSgpcjBs5Go81S/7+/x/MmaPEm
0:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAB4CAYAAAA5ZDbSAAAgAEl
1:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAB4CAYAAAA5ZDbSAAAY3U    
2:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAB4CAYAAAA5ZDbSAAAgAElE
3:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAAB4CAYAAAA5ZDbSAAAgAEl
```

Its a long string I did not just continue. I'm not sure if its an object, array or what. Is this possible to pass that value into PHP and then save the image into folder?

```
var image =  [];
$('.dz-image img').each(function(){
    image.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
console.log(image);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/380971/3859027

Comment: Can i append the array `image` into a FormData?

Comment: just treat it like any normal array, just pass it along in there

Answer (score 2):

in general, you're looking at a Data URI - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs for more info.

in this particular case, you seem to be looking at a base64 encoded PNG file - if you want to upload the PNG to a PHP script on the server, you actually have a TON of options around what happens where (and in what order), but one possible approach is to a) always assume you're dealing w/ base64 encoded PNGs (if you know that not to be true, then you'll have to handle the first two parts of the data URI),  b) upload data ($.post() the stuff after the comma) to PHP, c) base64 decode the data on the PHP side

Comment: Is there a difference if the image uploaded is JPEG or other than PNG?

Comment: the image is what it is - the content-type portion of the data URI will tell you the type of image, but there's no trivial way to convert from that type during the upload.  to a degree, it doesn't really matter though - if you just want to upload the binary data to save it to a folder on the server, the only possible value of knowing the "content type" is to give the file a meaningful extension.  knowing the TYPE of image really only affects what you plan to do w/ the file once you save it (which you didn't tell us about...yet)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value into PHP from javascript, consider to use ajax? In my experience, the http-post can transfer Array to PHP directly, like this:

```js
var image =  [];
$('.dz-image img').each(function(){
    image.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
//console.log(image);
//here, I use jQuery, but you can use any way of ohter javascript framework
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  tranditional:true,
  url:'saveImage.php',
  data:{"iamge":image},
  success:function(data){
    console.log(image)
  }
})
```

In the php side, if you need to save image address into database, just do it like insert data to database. If you want to save the image into folder, do like this: saveImage.php

```js
<?php
  $images = $_POST['image'];
  //here, you can code var_dump($image) to console the data you get

  foreach($images as $key=>$image){
    $image = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png:base64,','', $image));
    file_put_contents($key.'.jpg', $image);
  }
```

now, have a try?^-^